# How to start mongodb in windows 10

Tags: python, mongodb, server, pymongo

I have installed mongo-db from the Jupyter notebook using `!pip install pymongo`.

Now how to start mongodb. Is there any way to start mongodb through Juyter Notebook.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
#print (client)
#client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db  = client['test-database']
#print (db)
courses = db.courses
#print (courses)
course = {
    'author':'Mak',
    'course':'Data',
    'price': 100,
    'rating':5
    }
result = courses.insert_one(course)
```

I am getting `ServerSelectionTimeoutError Traceback (most recent call last)` since there is no mongodb started

Comment: try this once : Step 1: 'import pymongo'; then step 2: 
'client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")'

Comment: same error I got

Comment: open your mongodb connections & check whether it is successfully connected or not (click on the test button;then you can see one green tick if it is successfully connected )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pymongo is a client and you need a server too.

From the pymongo tutorial:

[image]

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to start the server from Jupyter Notebook

Comment: I would be surprised if it was

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @match

Install server before using it

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

go to folder where you installed mongodb

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>

start `mongo.exe`